# Build agent metric in Azure Devops pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We pay for a number of Microsoft hosted build agents in Azure pipelines. We have a lot of build pipelines, where many of them do jobs in parallel.

Are there any metrics I can use to see the utilization of the build agents and even more interesting, how many jobs are in queue for a free build agent?

Since this would be for the whole Azure Devops instance the Dashboard feature doesn't seems to be appropriate because it only seems to hold project specific metrics.

Answer (score 1):

Got to your Organization Settings-Parallel jobs blade.  This will give you the ability to view the jobs in progress.

As for metrics there is a [public](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-179-update#historical-graph-for-agent-pools-preview) preview just came out for this; however, I do not have it available yet.
Agent pool usage data is sampled and aggregated by the Analytics service every 10 mins. The number of jobs is plotted based on the max number of running jobs for the specified interval of time.

> This feature is enabled by default. To try it out, follow the guidance
> below.
>
> Within project settings, navigate to the pipelines “Agent pools” tab
> From the agent pool, select a pool (e.g., Azure Pipelines) Within the
> pool, select the “Analytics” tab